# How does one determine what size I-beam is needed?

Tags: walls, framing

I have a 22' wall that needs removed to open for a room addition.  I have a 4/12 roof, (11) 24' trusses that will need supported as I open up that room.  Thanks for any information you may be able to provide.  Much appreciated.

Comment: one employs the services of a structural engineer

Comment: This needs the services of a structural engineer for safety reasons.

Comment: Also see https://www.brighthubengineering.com/machine-design/40491-how-to-select-a-correctly-size-steel-i-beam/

Comment: This is one of those topics unfortunately where if you have to ask, you don't know enough to do the rest safely. Some things can't be learned on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to college and earn a degree in civil engineering.
2. Take and pass the EIT Exam.
3. Get a job in the business of determining appropriate beam sizes for varied projects and work there under the supervision of registered engineers for 5-10 years or so.
4. Get the recommendation of 2-3 of these engineers and then take and pass the PE Exam.
5. Congratulations!  Now you are qualified to make such determinations.

Comment: A good answer, but probably not what the OP wants to hear...

Comment: True but do people come here for real answers or just what they want to hear?